# Repository module implementation with Context

Tags: android, repository-pattern, android-architecture-components

I would like to implement `Repository` module to handle data operations. I have JSON file in `row` directory and want create concrete `Repository` implementation to get data from file. I'm not sure if I can use `Context` as attribute in the constructor or method of `Repository`.

e.g.

```
public class UserRepository {

    UserRepository() {}

    public List<User> loadUserFromFile(Context contex) {
        return parseResource(context, R.raw.users);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to use the Context for? You won't need it to access the file system...

Comment: I need Context to access resources. As I mentioned, I have my json file in thew raw directory.

Comment: You can pass context as a parameter, no problem.

Comment: Use DI Dagger2 to provide Context in your repository.

Comment: You mean raw directory

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, you should use DI (Dependency Injection) like [Dagger2](https://google.github.io/dagger/), to provide you `Context` something like,

**AppModule.class**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private Context context;

    public AppModule(@NonNull Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @NonNull
    public Context provideContext(){
        return context;
    }

}
```

**MyApplication.class**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static AppComponent appComponent;

    public static AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        appComponent = buildComponent();
    }

    public AppComponent buildComponent(){
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.class**

```
@Singleton
public class UserRepository {

    UserRepository() {}

    @Inject
    public List<User> loadUserFromFile(Context contex) {
        return parseResource(context, R.raw.users);
    }
}
```

Happy Coding..!!

Comment: The context should be retrieved from the activity which instantiate the model, which owns the repository, but not statically; it should be retrieved [on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38967293/4469112), that is it should be passed

Comment: Agree! This completely defies the logic of keeping a low coupling. Best way is to inject the context while repository object is created.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any harm in passing the context as an attribute. If you dislike the idea then you can retrieve the context via a convenient method : [Static way to get 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android?answertab=votes)

Comment: Please don't retrieve the context statically, retrieve it [on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38967293/4469112)